# How to get file contents in PHP - function doesn't seem to find it

Tags: php

I have this line in a function:

```
$template = file_get_contents('signup_template.html');
```

The problem is that PHP doesn't find the file, yet it is there in the same directory as the function.

Is there some other directory it should be in? In the root of the site?  Or maybe a permissions problem?

*Update:*

Got it to work with this:

```
$template = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/signup_template.html');
```

It seems the issue is that the full path is required to get file contents.

Also, the **DIR** was not the directory of the function (which was in a subdirectory), but the directory of the page which included the function.

Greg

Comment: What is your include path set to? It's likely looking there, rather than in the directory as the function.  An improvement might be to use the full file path, which is easy enough to get with `dirname(__FILE__)` (or, in PHP 5.3+, `__DIR__`)

Comment: No luck with `./signup_template.html` neither? Be sure, no typos in both - parameter and file name.

Comment: As @cale_b said above, maybe try ``file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/signup_template.html');``

Comment: May be there is a file named 'signup_template.htm' insted of .html extension

Comment: have you used include and the main php file which you are using exist on some other directory or root

Comment: @Kamiccolo, Checked that, files names are ok.

Comment: OK, got it to work with: `$template = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/signup_template.html');'